# Inverse Laplace transform of $\left(\frac{1+\alpha s}{1+\alpha(s-s_0)}\right)^p$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

I am hoping to identify the function $f(t)$ that has the following Laplace transform,

$$
\tilde f(s)=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt=\left(\frac{1+\alpha s}{1+\alpha(s-s_0)}\right)^p
$$

where $\alpha,s_0,p$ are positive parameters. Any suggestions about how to approach this problem?

Comment: You might get an useful result with inverse laplace transform: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform

Comment: In general, I find that using complex integration to evaluate inverse Laplace transforms only works out nicely in cases when the solution would have been more easily obtained via clever application of Laplace transform properties. But perhaps this particular problem requires complex integration. I'll note that Mathematica seems to be unable to calculate this inverse transform.

Comment: This type of inverse if related to the Laguerre polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Leucippus's hint, we have
$$\mathcal L^{-1} \!\left[ \frac 1 s \left( 1 + \frac 1 s \right)^p \right] =
L_p(-t), \\
\mathcal L^{-1} \!\left[ \left( 1 + \frac 1 s \right)^p \right] =
\frac d {d t} L_p(-t) = L_{p - 1}^{(1)}(-t) + \delta(t), \\
\mathcal L^{-1} \!\left[
 \left( \frac {1 + \alpha s} {1 + \alpha (s - s_0)} \right)^p \right] =
\mathcal L^{-1} \!\left[
 \left( 1 + \frac 1 {s/s_0 + 1/(\alpha s_0) - 1} \right)^p \right] = \\
s_0 e^{(s_0 - 1/\alpha)t} L_{p - 1}^{(1)}(-s_0 t) + \delta(t),$$
where $L_{p - 1}^{(1)}$ is the generalized Laguerre function.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Is there any way to evaluate a generalized Laguerre function for non-integer $p$?

Comment: Your expression simplifies to the same thing, because $f(t) \delta(t) = f(0) \delta(t)$. You won't be able to convert $L_p$ to elementary functions, but it can be converted to ${_1\hspace{-1px}F_1}$, if your software can evaluate that:
$$L_p(t) = {_1\hspace{-1px}F_1}(-p; 1; t),
\quad L_p^{(1)}(t) = (p + 1) \,{_1\hspace{-1px}F_1}(-p; 2; t).$$